# the first iitem is not pushed into a useState array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have a Nexjs application that I want to be able to upload images and store those images in a useState array variable and update it as the user adds more images. This works but somehow, the first item is never stored in the array. It is from the second item that gets stored. For example, if the user adds three images, image2, and image3 would be stored in the useState. The image1 won't be found. Here is the code: This is the helper function because I would be using the function in many components:

```
  export const selectFiles = (file: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
      const fileLen = file?.target?.files?.length as number 
       if(fileLen > 0){
       const img = file?.target?.files?.[0] as File;//this is the items I am missing the first image
       const prevImg = URL.createObjectURL(img);

      return {prevImg, img}
    }
    else return


   };
```

This is one of the places I used the function:

```
 const handleSelection = (file: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
    
    const result = selectFiles(file);
   
    dispatch({type: actionEnum.SELECTEDIMAGEUPLOAD, payload: result?.img});
    dispatch({type: actionEnum.IsSELECTED_IMAGES, payload: result?.prevImg});
   
   }
```

This is my `useReducer code`:

```
 case actionEnum.SELECTEDIMAGEUPLOAD:
        return{
            ...state,
            selectedImageUpload: [...state.selectedImageUpload, 
  action.payload]
        }
```

This is the input html tag:

```
 <input type="file" name="file" className=" absolute w-full opacity-0 h-5/6 top-0 bottom-0" 
  onChange={handleSelection} />
```

The state that is storing the images coming from `result?.img` is always missing the first image the user selected from their local storage.

Comment: Where is your reducer code? Also you mentioned the input is multiple file upload. But looking at the code it is single file upload only.

Comment: I would edit it. It is multiple but uploaded one by one and not at a go. I will also add my reducer code.